# When using BigQuery transfer service with a CSV is it possible to only transfer certain columns? Not, all columns?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am setting up a BigQuery transfer service to transfer a CSV stored in a GCS bucket into BigQuery.

However, I don't need all the columns in the CSV file. Is there a way of limiting the columns I transfer without having to manually remove the columns before the transfer?

Or, if I limited the columns in my BQ table to the ones I need, will BQ just ignore the other columns in the CSV file?

I have read the relevant page in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer) but there is no mention of limiting columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want if you manually specify the target table schema with the columns that you need. Then when you use the transfer service you need to set the option `ignore_unknown_values` to true.

Let's say I have a CSV on Google Cloud Storage with the following data:

```
"First"|"Second"|"Ignored"
"Third"|"Fourth"|"Ignored"
```

Then I have the table with the name `test` and schema like:

```
first_col   STRING  NULLABLE    
second_col  STRING  NULLABLE
```

After configuring the transfer service with web UI and checking the checkbox "Ignore unknown values" I get the following data in the table:

| first_col | second_col |
| --- | --- |
| First | Second |
| Third | Fourth |

Read more about it in this [section](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#setting_up_a_cloud_storage_transfer).